# Android Wearable Message Api send message onDestroy()

Tags: android, wear-os

I have a watch face running on wear and I would like to send a message to my companion app when the watch face is changed. I looked at the docs and found `onDestroy` or `onSurfaceDestroyed` to be appropriate methods of `WallpaperService.Engine`

However, the watch face is destroyed before the message is sent.

The goal is to detect when the user stops using my watch face.

Thank you!

Comment: Can't you start an [Intent]Service to handle that in the background?

Comment: I haven't tried, but i will give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: Starting a service right before `super.onDestroy()` didn't seem to work.

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot to call a method! Starting a service works fine. It would have been simpler if there was a way to detect when the watch was on the "watch face selection" screen.